# makechapterstyle memoir Undefined control sequence

Tags: memoir

I try to make a chapterstyle in memoir using lualatex like in the picture

[image]

But there is a Undefined control sequence Error.
An other problem is "You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode." With using \makeatletter ... \makeatother the Error disappears but the Chapter (Kapitel) in front of the chapternumber disappears to.

Here is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{fourier-otf}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{blindtext}


%% Chapterstyle
%\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{diss}{%
    
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace*{\beforechapskip}}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{
    \normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so \@Kapitel}
\renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{\space}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter}
\renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{\par\nobreak\vskip \midchapskip}
\renewcommand\printchapternonum{}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{
    \normalfont\huge\bfseries\scshape \raggedleft ##1}
\renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\par\nobreak\vskip\afterchapskip}

%\makeatother
}% end{diss}
\chapterstyle{diss}

\begin{document}
   \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

I cannot debug this any further. Can anybody help?

Comment: Everytime you use a macro with `@` in its name you need to have `\makeatletter....\makeatother` around the construction. Where does `\@Kapitel` come from? Never seen that before

Comment: In the comments in the MWE the `\makeatother` should be switched with the line below it. Assitional you haven't defined `\so` anywhere. Coming from `soul`?

Comment: \@Kapitel is from the memoir documentation:
renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{%
\chapnamefont\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}}

Comment: No `\@Kapitel` is not mentioned anywhere in the memoir documentation, I for one would know. It mentions `\enewcommand*{\printchaptername}{% \chapnamefont\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}}` don't change macros if you do not know what they do (`\@chapapp` is `\chaptername` unless appendix mode is active in which case it is `\appendixname`)

Answer (score 0):

Thats the Answer: Thx for help!

```
%% Chapterstyle
\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{diss}{%
    
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace*{\beforechapskip}}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{
    \normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\@chapapp}
\renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{\space}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter}
\renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{\par\nobreak\vskip \midchapskip}
\renewcommand\printchapternonum{}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{
    \normalfont\huge\bfseries\scshape \raggedleft ##1}
\renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\par\nobreak\vskip\afterchapskip}

}% end{diss}
\makeatother
\chapterstyle{diss}
```